# Refresh included php file while using cli

Tags: php, command-line-interface

I'm using PHP CLI and accept user input in a loop such that the script never terminates, and I include a few files that get updated regularly. I was wondering if there is a way to refresh these files every time input is processed so that updates show without terminating the script.

Comment: PHP parses the script when you first start running, and then executes the parsed script. It doesn't re-read the file unless you restart the script.

Answer (score 0):

Simple:

```
 while(file_exists("looper"))
 {
       //your code here
 }
```

Comment: Will this cause errors with redefining functions/classes, and if the file exists all the time then this will always run, no?

Comment: You could use `runkit_function_remove()` to remove a function before reloading the include file that redefines it.

Comment: But there doesn't seem to be anything similar for classes.